# Scaling with animation using Raphael 2

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a set of path elements that I'm trying to scale with animation. Based on some demos I've seen this should be possible, but I'm having no luck.

I've tried the following:

```
set.mouseover(function() {
    this.toFront().animate({'fill':'green', 'scale':'5 5'}, 50);
});
```

I also attempted things like `'scale':[5, 5]` based on some other samples I found.
Neither of these of work.

The following does work, but no animation is involved:

```
set.mouseover(function() {
    this.scale(2, 2);
});
```

I'm using version 2.0.1 of raphael.
Any suggestions about how I can get this to work?

**Edit**: The discrepancy between examples and my tests are possibly due to the update to Raphael 2, I'm looking into these changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, got it going, it was due to updates with Raphael 2.

The following worked for me:

```
    this.toFront().animate({'fill':'green', 'transform':"s2 2"}, 50);
```

Thanks to [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/raphaeljs/browse_thread/thread/cea019d51733146d) for helping me figure it out.